# Word VBA /n --> convert to hyperlink

Tags: vba, text, hyperlink, ms-word

I am trying to write a vba where if it finds the word Bacon, it:

1. Underlines it
2. Adds the http://www.bacon.com right after it
3. Goes to a new line

My problem is that when using the "/n" manually in word the "http://www.bacon.com" gets converted to a clickable link. When using either of the  VbNewLine; aVbNewLine or VbCrLf or Vblf does not get converted to a clickable link.

```
Sub InsertVariety_Links()
Dim sFindText As String
'Start from the top of the document
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
sFindText = "Bacon"
Selection.Find.Execute sFindText
Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
  Selection.Range.Underline = wdUnderlineWords
  Selection.InsertAfter Text:=" http://www.bacon.com" & VbNewLine
  Selection.MoveRight
  Selection.Find.Execute
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error... for me the address is not a hyperlink. That said, 2 ways to approach: (1) remove the hyperlinks using `.Delete` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091785/how-do-you-remove-hyperlinks-from-a-microsoft-word-document. (2) separate the VbNewLine in another .InsertAfter command and see if that works

Comment: Long day ... When using either of the VbNewLine; aVbNewLine or VbCrLf or Vblf the " http://www.bacon.com " does not get converted to a clickable link.